# Sending OneSignal notification crashes server

Tags: mysql, magento, crash, onesignal, web-push

So I came across a strange issue: as soon as I hit send Web Push notification in One Signal dashboard, the Mysql server dies - memory usage goes to 100% and the cpu goes nuts. Soon after it crashes and Mysql resumes normal operation.

I must mention that this happens even if images used in the notification are not hosted on the same server. Even if nobody actually clicks the notifications for the first 5minutes, it still crashes.
Our list has about 11.000 subscribers.

What could be the issue? I just dont know what to try anymore. Tried upping the max_connections and other my.cnf settings according to mysqltuner.pl. No luck.

This is happening on a Magento 1.9 store, with the following specs: 24gb RAM, 240gb SSD, 12-core 2ghz, CentOS7, running Apache with REDIS, php5.5.

UPDATE: Fixed by revising the OneSignal settings and the way notifications are sent + enabled skip-name-resolve in my.cnf.

Answer (score 1):

I have alerted this issue to onesignal several times but each time they suggest to go for good hosting service.
I think the problem is with the onesignal wp plugin. I have a dedicated cloud server from vultr but still site goes down right after new push notification. 
You will have no problem if you send push notification directly from onesignal dashboard.
Because all my request goes to deaf ears, now I do not use onesignal.

Comment: If you could post (here or at pastebin.com) current complete my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  will try to assist.

Comment: Thanks for helping :-). Please see pastebin https://pastebin.com/QvzetUDv